# Problems encountered using Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Use Autofac
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Replace the default controller activator
//builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IControllerActivator, CustomControllerActivator>());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

CustomControllerActivator.cs

```
public class CustomControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    public object Create(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // `serviceProvider` the object is `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider` type
        var serviceProvider = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        ...
    }

    public void Release(ControllerContext context, object controller)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

WeatherForecastController.cs

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScope serviceProvider;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger,IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        //`serviceProvider` the object is `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider` type
        serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

I checked the source code and didn't see you replace 'IControllerActivator' or 'IControllerActivatorProvider', so I don't quite understand how you operate the activation of the controller

I don't understand how you replace the object of 'HttpContext.RequestServices' with the type of 'Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider'

**Thank you very much for asking for relief**

Comment: I think you need to do something like `builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IControllerActivator, CustomControllerActivator>());` in your startup.

Comment: I used this to replace the default controller activator and found the member `context.HttpContext. Requestservices` is `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider` type, but I don't know where or when Autofac is replaced
All I know is `builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());` Role played